# If $f(z)=u(x, y) +i v(x, y)$ is analytic then show that $\log(|f(z)|)$ is Zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I have done this by using Laplace equation as I assumed $\log(|f(z)|)$ to be some variable '$w$' and proved the (second derivative of '$w$' with respect to $u$)  +(second derivative of '$w$' with respect to $v$) is zero. 
Was it correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is holomorphic on some open set $D$ in $\mathbb C$ and if $f$ has no zeroes in $D$, then $\log(|f|)$ is harmonic in $D$.

Show your proof, then we will see whether your proof is correct.

Comment: I have added the picture of the proof which I have done. Please let me know whether I am right

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=e^z$ is analytic and $\log|f|=x\neq0$.